# Pressing CapsLock key messes up the keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I've been using my Lenovo X1 Carbon for last 5 years perfectly fine until today when suddenly I pressed <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and it started going haywire. I tried both the USB keyboard and the laptop keyboard and same issue.

After restarting, the problem seems to go away until I press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> again. Some of the behaviour after pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>: pressing pretty much any alphabet key just mutes/unmutes. Pressing <kbd>F</kbd> just makes the key get stuck. Pressing arrow keys just selects random sections. I've tried uninstalling both keyboard devices via device manager, and restarting, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is the same on both the built in keyboard and external keyboards you connect, the issue is more likely software related or caused.

You should upgrade all drivers and firmware, and consider reinstalling your OS if other things do not work.